# Java program unable to create lock on Neo4j database

Tags: neo4j

I am getting the following error while connecting to Neo4j:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:  org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter@1798b372' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:281)
at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:106)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:88)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:207)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:69)
at com.neo4j.NeoStart.createDatabase(NeoStart.java:41)
at com.neo4j.NeoStart.main(NeoStart.java:26)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter@1798b372' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:497)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:104)
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:259)
... 6 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockException: Could not create lock file
at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:74)
at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.start(StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.java:40)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:491)
```

I have installed neo4j as: **apt-get install neo4j** in ubuntu 12.04

DB_PATH I am using is as below:
private static final String neo4j_DB_PATH="**/var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db**";

Please help me to resolve this problem...

Comment: Most likely you are starting up multiple databases. Neo4j only allows one program to edit/read the database files at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that the uid which the neo4j server uses has write privileges to the data directory? And are you sure that there are no multiple instances running? You can check that with a `ps axf|grep neo4j` on your terminal.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I tried some guess for the possible solution like changing the destination database file...Woela...It worked.... So for some reason that location was inaccessible...I changed the DB_PATH to "/var/lib/neo4j/data/random_name.db".

Comment: One other thing: `private static final String neo4j_DB_PATH="/var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db";` sounds like you are accessing the same db path from your own java program that the neo4j server which you installed with apt does. So if you disable the auto startup of the neo4j server in your runlevel configuration you should be able to access that database (when the permissions are correct).